# Solve the system of equation using substitution method

Tags: systems-of-equations, substitution

Here are the equations:

$$c+6d=7\text{ and }-c-2d=-2$$

I tried to do it but in the end, I get the wrong answer. The intersection point is a decimal.

This is how I tried doing it:

I first simplified the first equation which would be $$d=-\frac{1}{6}c+\frac{7}{6}$$

Then I substituted and this is how it looks: $$-c-2\left(-\frac{1}{6}c+\frac{7}{6}\right)=-2$$

I simplified the equation and got $$c=\frac{13}{6}-\frac{6}{3}$$

for the answer, I got $c=\frac{1}{6}$

last I substituted $-c-2d=-2$ to $-\frac{1}{6}-2d=-2$

I got $d=\frac{11}{12}$ but I got it wrong

Comment: Do you know how to use the method? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Show your attempt by editing your original post (do not reply in the comments with an attempt).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)  like "I tried but did not find", [format your equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and use a more descriptive title.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "*I tried to do it but in the end, I get the wrong answer*"  If you were to show your attempt we could point to your mistake.  Since you did not show your attempt, we don't know what mistake you made and aren't as able to help you avoid the same mistake in the future.  It is more helpful to show how to avoid mistakes than it is to just give the answer.

Comment: @CrSb0001 It's not hard to tell what Vale is asking (a solution), but (s)he does not seem to be aware of the rules on this site.

Comment: @AnneBauval I will try to keep that in mind when reviewing posts.

Comment: I already edited my question, so if you can please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For advice, it is often preferred to avoid fractions whenever possible.  Rather than solving for $d$ and using that to substitute, it would have been cleaner to solve for $c$ here, it would have just been $c=7-6d$ with no fractions necessary.

Following your work, you got $d=\frac{7}{6}-\frac{1}{6}c$.  This is correct

You continued with $-c-2d=-2$ and substituting in giving $-c-2\left(\frac{7}{6}-\frac{1}{6}c\right) = -2$ which is good.

You say that you "*simplified the equation and got...*" $c=\frac{13}{6}-\frac{6}{3}$.  You do not show how you simplified to get to this, but this is wrong.  Let us work through the simplification in more detail:

$$-c-2\left(\frac{7}{6}-\frac{1}{6}c\right)=-2$$

Distribute the negative 2 on the parentheses

$$-c+(-2)\times\frac{7}{6} + (-2)\times(-\frac{1}{6}c)=-2$$

Note that $6=2\times 3$ and so $(-2)\times\frac{x}{6}=(-2)\times\frac{x}{2\times 3}=-\frac{x}{3}$ so this simplifies to:

$$-c-\frac{7}{3}+\frac{1}{3}c = -2$$

move constants to one side and combine

$$-\frac{2}{3}c = \frac{1}{3}$$

multiply both sides by $-\frac{3}{2}$

$$c = -\frac{1}{2}$$

From here we can finish the problem by back-substitution.

---

If we were to have started by solving for $c$ we would have had $c=7-6d$, and then substituting in to the second expression we would have had $(7-6d)+2d=2$ which is easier to work with than having to manage fractions at the start.

If we were to continue with this,

$$(7-6d)+2d=2$$

$$7-4d=2$$

$$4d=5$$

$$d=\frac{5}{4}$$

Then back substituting:

$$c+2d=2$$

$$c+2\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)=2$$

$$c+\frac{5}{2}=2$$

$$c = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got -c-7/3+1/3c=-2

Comment: Can you slove it using c=7-6d please

Comment: @Vale added more steps.  Common pitfalls are not distributing negatives correctly, or messing up with simplifying fractions, etc...  Without more details I can not say specifically how you messed up, just that you did during your attempts at simplification.  Your approach was correct, but your execution was flawed.

Comment: Thanks now if you had to graph it, how would you do it?

Comment: I see that when you did (7-6d)+2d=2 you removed the negative signs. Why?

Comment: "*How would you graph it?*"  I'd treat each expression as lines and graph the lines.  An easy way to graph the line $c+2d=2$ would be to imagine what happens if $c=0$ to get the point on the $d$-axis that the line crosses (*that would be $d=1$ so the point $(0,1)$*), and then get the point on the $c$-axis that the line crosses by imagining instead that $d=0$ (*which would mean $c=2$ so the point $(2,0)$*).  I'd then use a ruler to connect the dots and extend the line a bit in each direction...  Do that with the other expression as well and see where they cross.

Comment: @Vale $-4d=-5$ is the same thing as $4d=5$.  "*you removed the negative signs.  Why?*"  Because working with positive numbers is often easier and leads to less mistakes.

Comment: How is -4d=-5 the same as 4d=5?

Comment: By multiplying each side by $-1$... or equivalently by adding $4d$ to each side and adding $5$ to each side....

Comment: oh okay, so if I had an equation that is something like this: -2d-4=-9 you could multiply it bu -1 and convert it into positive?

Comment: Yes, that would become $2d+4=9$.  Now you can safely subtract 4 from each side without worrying about getting confused by signs and if it should go from 9 to 13 or from 9 to 5.

Comment: Ok, and I saw that you got c+5/2=2 when your substituting, but can it be too 3/4?

Comment: I don't understand that question.  $\frac{3}{4}$ does not appear in the problem or in any of my steps shown.  $\frac{5}{2}=2.5$ is not equal to $\frac{3}{4}=0.75$.  I don't know where $\frac{3}{4}$ came from in your question or why you thought to ask about it.

Comment: I know you got c+5/2=2, but how did you get 5/2?

Comment: @Vale because we found earlier that $d=\frac{5}{4}$.  We substituted back into $c+2d$ and so we replaced $d$ with what we found that it was equal to.  We had then $c+2\times\frac{5}{4}$ which is equal to $c+\frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: okay, thank you, i think i got it

Comment: Question: so would the intercept point be (-1/2; 5/4) ?